# Using resources from different packages

Tags: android, android-styles, android-appwidget

I have a style defined in `style.xml` in a package.

Can that style be used in a **different package** programmetically like

```
textView.setTextAppearance(R.style.style_from_different_package)
```

I am trying this but receiving `symbol not found` error.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a different module u can include the module in "settings.gradle" and add implementation project(path: ':module-name') in app gradle file.